# c# Make some tasks asynchronous

Tags: c#

My Code:

```
ConcurrentQueue<string> concurrentQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  try {
    var task1 = Task.Run(() => GetMessages());
    var task2 = Task.Run(() => GetOrderBookData());
    UpdateOrderBook();
  } catch(Exception ex)
  { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); } 
}

private void GetMessages() {
  var w = new WebSocketConfiguration(); //class to connect o websocket to get messages
  w.OnWSOpen += w_OnWSOpen;
  w.OnWSMessage += w_OnWSMessage;
  w.OnWSError += w_OnWSError;
  w.OnWSClose += w_OnWSClose;
  w.SetWebSocketSharpEvents(); // connect to websocket
}

void w_OnWSMessage(string message)
{
  this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
  {
    listBox1.Items.Add(message);
    concurrentQueue.Enqueue(message);
    // To refresh the GUI simultaneously as the background process progresses
    Application.DoEvents();                 
  }));            
}

private void UpdateOrderBook() {
  if (!concurrentQueue.IsEmpty) {
    string jsonString;
    while (concurrentQueue.TryDequeue(out jsonString))
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:

```
private void GetOrderBookData() {
  var OrderList = new List<string>();

  // Add items using Add method 
  OrderList.Add("order1");
  OrderList.Add("order2");
  OrderList.Add("order3");
  OrderList.Add("order4");
  OrderList.Add("order5");
  dgOrders.DataSource = OrderList;
}
```

In my code UpdateOrderBook is called first and then `GetMessages()` is called.  I want `GetMessages()` to keep running and once started it should call `GetOrderBookData()` to fill the values in a grid. Now I want to read messages from the queue and update the grid by calling `UpdateOrderBook()`.

How do I make it asynchronous?

EDIT:

GetMessages() will send me more orders which I have to add/delete in the grid.

**EDIT2**

Steps: I want to call

(1) `GetMessages()`  this will keep bringing the messages in separate thread

(2) Once the messages starts coming in (1) then call the `GetOrderData()` this will fetch the order details and insert them in datagrid and the its task is finished here

(3) `UpdateOrderBook()` this will now update the existing datagrid (which already has some data from step 2). Here in this method I want to check the queue and have to iterate the concurrentqueue then do some processing and then insert that record in the existing grid.

Hope this is clear now. The two process (1,3) would run asynchronously but for the first time it should process in above order.

I got stuck in making them run asynchronously.

Comment: Please do not ever call `Application.DoEvents()` in your code - especially production code. It's only in .NET for backward compatibility with VB6. It can cause all sort of re-entrancy issues and they are a nightmare to debug.

Comment: Also you should never catch every exception, i.e. `catch(Exception ex)`. Have a read of this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: You can use Task.Run if you need fire-and-forget for a method.
`Task.Run(() => GetMessages());`

Comment: Ideally, I would not recommend using WebSocket, instead use SignalR, which does all this automatically.

Comment: I am working on windows 7 and SignalR does not work on it

Comment: @user1254053 of course it does! It's *websockets* that don't. Native support for websockets was added in Windows 8. SignalR will detect the *client's* capabilities and use the appropriate notification mechanism

Comment: a independent thread run `GetMessage()` when your application startup, and `UpdateOrderBook()` running in other new thread at the same time. when `GetMessage()` method receive any data, then call `GetOrderBookData()`.`GetMessage()` is getting some datas from remote server, then `GetOrderBookData()` handle them and put them in a queue, last `UpdateOrderBook()` showing them in a `DataGrid` Control. do these are your think?

Comment: Use a semaphore

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ConcurrentQueue<string> messageQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string> ();

        public Form1 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        private async void Form1_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var task1 = GetMessages ();
            var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew (GetOrderBookData);

            dgOrders.DataSource = await task2;

            await Task.WhenAll (task1, task2);

            UpdateOrderBook ();
        }


        public async Task GetMessages ()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                string message = await Task.Run (() => GetMessage (i));

                messageQueue.Enqueue (message);
                listBox1.Items.Add (message);
            }
        }


        private string GetMessage (int id)
        {
            Thread.Sleep (500); // simulate work
            return "some-message-" + id;
        }


        private IReadOnlyList<string> GetOrderBookData ()
        {
            Thread.Sleep (2000); // simulate work

            return new List<string> { "order 1", "order 2", "order 3" };
        }


        private void UpdateOrderBook ()
        {
            string message = null;

            string jsonString;

            while (messageQueue.TryDequeue (out jsonString))
            {
                message += jsonString + "\r\n";
            }

            MessageBox.Show (message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Asynchronous methods that you define by using async and await are
>   referred to as async methods. The good thing is that you can rewrite your code to tell the compiler to treat those methods as async. Now, you should be aware that if you don't call the await method inside an asynchronous methods it will not tell the compiler to stop the execution on that point and continue later. They good news is that you can execute the await over your method even if they return just void(Task)

What about this.

> TaskFactory.StartNew Method (Action) Creates and starts a task.
>   Parameters:action Type: System.Action The action delegate to execute
>   asynchronously.[Documentation Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
        Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(GetMessages);
        Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(GetOrderBookData).ContinueWith(t => UpdateOrderBook());

        Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).Wait();
```

This is another approach too

```
void Main()
{
            var cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            Action action1 = async () =>
            {
                await GetMessages();
            };

            Action action2 = async () =>
            {
                //wait for filling the GetOrderBookData
                await GetOrderBookData();
                //on this point you should have the data to refresh on the grid
                UpdateOrderBook();
            };

            Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(action1, cancelSource.Token);
            Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(action2, cancelSource.Token);

            //when you want to cancel the task just call Cancel over cancelSource  => cancelSource.Cancel();

            Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).Wait();
}

//Be sure to mark your methods with the async keyword
private async Task UpdateOrderBook()
{
...
}

private async Task GetOrderBookData()
{
 ....
}

private async Task GetMessages()
{
 ....
}
```

Comment: It's not asynchronous.

Comment: It also doesn't actually start the tasks. This code would just deadlock.

Comment: It's still not asynchronous.

Comment: Yes, but your code is still not asynchronous. It's like saying that bricks are solid so if I build a house from bricks then the house must be solid too. Similarly, your code, built from asynchronous parts, is not asynchronous.

Comment: Additionally `GetMessages` is *already* asynchronous, `UpdateOrderBook` doesn't need to run after `GetOrderBookData`, but it *does* need to be updated to not break from the loop too early (or to have the code restructured, which would be better) and `GetOrderBookData` isn't shown, so we don't even know what that does or how to handle it properly.

Comment: And it's still not asynchronous. You've just built a bigger house with more bricks, but the final code isn't asynchronous.

Comment: @Enigmativity you were right, I just updated the answer with the changes, any idea to improve it will be accepted.

Comment: @Servy I just split it into action2 to await for GetOrderBookData before UpdateOrderBook

Comment: @Zinov Your new solution is *much* more broken than the previous solution.  You still have *all* of the problems that I mentioned previously, but now you have `async void` methods when you shouldn't

Comment: @Servy, GetMessages it is not asynchronous because it use the websockets internally. Actually it is more a Producer/Consumer Queue. It should work with the BackgoundWorker to handle the UI for the UpdateOrderBook, anyways, you can suggest for help him

Comment: @Zinov It *is* asynchronous because it will return pretty much immediately and not block the caller for an extended period of time, allowing the productive work to complete after the method returns, rather than waiting for it.  *That* is what makes something asynchronous.  There's no reason for it to do its work in a background thread.  There's also no reason to use a BackgroundWorker when you have the TPL to do the same thing more easily.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //get messages asynchronously
            Task getMessagesTask = new Task(GetMessages);
            getMessagesTask.Start();

            GetOrderBookData();

            Task updateTask = new Task(UpdateOrderBook);

            //check if concurrent queue has items
            if(!concurrentQueue.IsEmpty)
            {
                updateTask.Start();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

To make this code asynchronous you have to do something like this:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var t1 = Task.Run(() => GetMessages());
    var t2 = Task.Run(() => GetOrderBookData());
    var t3 = Task.Run(() => UpdateOrderBook());
    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);
}
```

Now, there is a still a problem with your code in that it seems that `UpdateOrderBook` is dependent on the result of `GetMessages`. It seems that you are doing some sort of wait and check type loop in `UpdateOrderBook`. That's not a great idea.

Also the code for `GetOrderBookData` isn't even in your question.

It would be awesome to have the three methods fully implemented and posted in your question so that we can see how this all hangs together and then we could provide a better solution.

Comment: `Now, there is a still a problem with your code in that it seems that UpdateOrderBook is dependent on the result of GetMessages` Where is that dependency shown in the question?  It specifically indicates otherwise with how it's coded.  ` It seems that you are doing some sort of wait and check type loop in UpdateOrderBook` And you didn't fix that problem.  As to the last point, if you feel the question doesn't provide enough information to be answered then *don't answer it*.

Comment: Your answer also has all of the same problems I mention on Zinov's answer.

Comment: @Servy - `UpdateOrderBook ` dequeues values that were added in by the  handler `w_OnWSMessage` which is triggered in the `GetMessages` method. There's enough information in the question to see that.

Comment: @Servy - My code does somewhat fix the "wait and check loop" as it pushes it off of the UI thread into a background task.

Comment: So how does that mean that `UpdateOrderBook` is dependant on `GetOrderBookData`, as you wrote it up in your code?  And anyway, no, it *doesn't* need to run after `GetMessages`.  It will simply wait in the loop until the events fired from `GetMessages` queue up items, so it can be started immediately, if you use this (rather poor) design.  Pushing that method into a thread pool thread doesn't fix the major design problems here, nor does it address all of the other major problems with your answer that I've mentioned.

Comment: What you are doing doesn't has any warranty that t3 will be executed after t2 or simply, it can finish before t2. @Servy was right on that, that's why I spitted on an Action delegate

Comment: @Servy - Yes, I see the point about the order of the code running. I've fixed my code on that point. And I did say that this approach "does somewhat fix" with the key emphasis on "somewhat". `UpdateOrderBook` is still dependant on `GetMessages` and I did mention the issues around how the implementation is bad regarding this.

Comment: @Servy - By the way, I did test this code before posting to ensure that it was running asynchronously as the OP requested.

Comment: @Enigmativity So you posted an answer that you know is bad.  Why in the world would you be so cruel as to knowingly post a bad answer, and why would you be surprised that an answer that *you think is a bad answer* would get downvotes.  You've now fixed one out of like 5 problems I've brought up with your answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity Considering that you don't even know what `GetOrderBookData` you couldn't possibly test it to ensure that the code actually works properly.

Comment: @Servy - I didn't post a bad answer. I posted an answer that improves the OP's bad design and noted other deficiencies. There's not much more I could do without the OP posting a [mcve].

Comment: @Servy - No, I didn't ensure that the code actually works - I couldn't possibly do that without a [mcve]. What I did was test that the code I posted was asynchronous as the OP requested. Read the exact wording on my comment. I was particularly careful with my wording.

Comment: @Enigmativity You posted an answer that you think is a bad solution, and it didn't work, and it still has numerous problems that I've pointed out that you haven't fixed.  Again, if the question doesn't provide enough information to be answered *then don't answer it*, rather than posting a bad answer and excusing it by saying that the question is incomplete.

Comment: @Enigmativity So you don't see the problems with posting an answer that doesn't work?  If you don't realize that having an answer *actually work* is a rather important quality of a good answer then I don't even know how to respond to that.  Why would you think posting answers that don't actually work would be helpful?